# How do I find my shelved changes in tfs Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2008, tfvc, shelveset, unshelve

I am new to TFS, and I have shelved some changes of my code, however now I need to get those changes and continue working on my project. How can I find my shelveset on VS2008 (this is the version of vs that I have to use for my project) and how can I start using it so I can continue with my project?

I tried righ click on the projects file in Source Control, but the option Find is not available unlike VS2015.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Visual Studio 2008 docs are still online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms181403(v=vs.90)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511). The <kbd>Unshelve</kbd> button is hidden in the Pending Changes window and in the <kbd>File</kbd>-><kbd>Source Control</kbd> menu in the top-level menu bar of visual studio.

> Whereas you can restore a changeset into a workspace using the Get command, you must use the Unshelve Command to restore a shelveset. You can use the Unshelve button in the Pending Changes window to restore one, some, or all the pending changes in a shelveset to your workspace. For more information about the Pending Changes window, see How to: Check In Pending Changes. When you unshelve all the changes in a shelveset to a workspace using Visual Studio, the pending changes information with which the items are associated is restored to the Pending Changes window also.

See: [Shelve and unshelve pending changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms181404(v=vs.90)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511)

Generally, when the UI is confusing, consider falling back to the commandline tools:

From any folder in your workspace from a visual studio command prompt:

```
# List Shelves
tf shelvesets 

# Unshelve
tf unshelve "shelveset name"
```

You can also use a newer version of Visual Studio to do your source control interactions and develop from Visual Studio 2008.